# fixing NSWindow size?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

How can we fix the size of NSWindow so that user should not be able to resize it jus by dragging it with mouse or is there a way so that all the subviews window resizes when users changes the size of window , actually the problem is that when user changes size ofwindow , subviews do not resizses thats i  wanted to lock window resizing?

Answer (score 6):

I may be missing the point here (and a bit late), but can you not set the 'constraints' options on the window itself?

If the min and max sizes are the same, it prevents resizing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the answer you're after, but you could prevent the re-size by disabling the resize indicator (via `setShowsResizeIndicator`) and then implementing the...

```
- (NSSize)windowWillResize:(NSWindow *)sender toSize:(NSSize)frameSize
```

...NSWindowDelegate delegate method so that it simply returns the existing window size.

Odd that there's no "setCanResize:" method, but there you go.

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes you're using Interface Builder for your window layout:

To get the subviews to resize, go to the Size Inspector (command-3) and, for each subview, set its Autoresizing struts and stretchies (click red lines in rectangle) until the preview anim does what you want. Remember:
(1) If a parent view has no stretch, neither will its children; 
(2) If you're using scrollbars, they will never appear if the content is stretchable in the same direction as the scrollbar.

If you really need a locked window, with no controls for resizing, you can uncheck those options in the Attributes Inspector (command-1). Or, more simply, make an IBOutlet for the window and put this in your code:

```
[self.theWindow setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
```